# Generating telerik report multiple time according to multiValue parameter

Tags: telerik, reporting

I want to generate telerik report multiple times.
1. I have myReport.trdx
2. In my application, in viewer, I see use this report, I choooes parameters and can generated preview, can export aso. Let us say: this parameter has crucial parameter, named myParam1. It is set as single value, mergable = false.
3. My task is:
a). Add to this report additional parameter named myParm1_MultiValue, which has multiValue set to true. This I have done in trdx file.
b). During raport generation, obtain the value of myParm1_MultiValue.
If I manage it in reportViewer.html, it's grate. **THIS I CAN'T MANAGE.**
c). Then I pass count of selected myParm1_MultiValue to report resolver, together with report string.
d). In report resolver, instead of creating the original report instant, I create multiple instances of the original report, as many as myParm1_MultiValue count.
e). In reportViewer.html in parameter edititor, I past (somehow), the myParm1_MultiValue particular values to the particular report instances.

I can statically produce instances of report.

```
In ReportViewer.html
$("#reportViewer1")
            .telerik_ReportViewer({
                serviceUrl: "api/reports",
                templateUrl: 
'ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-FA.html',
                reportSource: {
                    report: reportName + "|5" //added static count
                },

In ReportResolver
protected override ReportSource ResolveReport(string report)
    { 
        if (!report.Contains("|"))
        {
            if (report.StartsWith(_startsWithValue))
            {
                report = report.Replace(_startsWithValue, _customReportsPath);
            }
            return base.ResolveReport(report);
        }
        else
        {
            var massReportParams = report.Split('|');
            report = massReportParams[0];

            if (report.StartsWith(_startsWithValue))
            {
                report = massReportParams[0].Replace(_startsWithValue, _customReportsPath);
            }

            var book = new ReportBook();
            for (var i = 0; i < int.Parse(massReportParams[1]); i++)
            {
                var resolvedReport = base.ResolveReport(report);
                book.ReportSources.Add(resolvedReport);
            }
            return new InstanceReportSource { ReportDocument = book };
        }
    }
```

I want to replace "|5" with COUNT read myParam1_MultiValue.VALUE.
As a result I want to see in running application in report viewer, in preview as well as in exported file, generated multiple reports, each coresponding to particular selected myParm1_MultiValue items.

My main problem is, how to obtaint the myParam1_MultiValue in the reportViewer.html

Can someone help? 
Jola K.